Как объединить два класса с разными обработчиками мыши
Подскажите пожалуйста!!!Мне нужно объединить два класса, у которых немного различаются обработчики мыши. Первый класс рисует круг по нажатиям мыши, другой класс рисует прямоугольник. Класс прямоугольника наследуется от класс круга. Я хочу по тому, какой CheckBox активен, рисовать нужную фигуру. Как мне это сделать? Код обоих классов представлен ниже.
partial class Ellipse : Form
{
    protected virtual CheckBox checkBox1 { get; set; }

    protected virtual int numberOfElipse { get; set; }
    protected virtual int indexToResize { get; set; }

    protected virtual Dictionary<int, List<Point>> dictOfPoints { get; set; }
    protected virtual Dictionary<int, List<Point>> dictToMoveSides { get; set; }
    

    protected virtual bool checkToResizeSides  { get; set; }

    protected virtual Point point { get; set; }
    
    protected virtual  Point newMousePosition { get; set; }
    protected virtual Point movingMouse { get; set; }
    protected virtual Point ChangeColorPoint { get; set; }

    Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 3);

    public Ellipse()
    {
        this.Size = new Size(700, 500);
        base.DoubleBuffered = true;
        checkBox1 = new CheckBox();
        checkBox1.Size = new Size(60, 20);
        checkBox1.Location = new Point(290, 50);
        checkBox1.Text = "Ellipse";
        checkBox1.Parent = this;
    }
    protected virtual void Mouse_Down(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left && checkBox1.Checked)
        {
            point = newMousePosition = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
        }
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left && !checkBox1.Checked)
        {
            movingMouse = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
        }
    }
    protected virtual void Mouse_Move(MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left && checkBox1.Checked)
        {
            newMousePosition = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
        }
        if (checkToResizeSides && e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            if (indexToResize != int.MaxValue)
            {
                newMousePosition = dictOfPoints[indexToResize][1];
                point = dictOfPoints[indexToResize][0];
                int differenceX = movingMouse.X - e.X;
                int differenceY = movingMouse.Y - e.Y;
                int indexToMoveSide = dictToMoveSides[indexToResize].IndexOf(ChangeColorPoint);

                Resize(indexToMoveSide, differenceX, differenceY);

                movingMouse = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
            }
            Replace(indexToResize);
        }
        else if (!checkBox1.Checked)
        {
            ChangeColorPoint = FindNecessaryPoint(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
            if (ChangeColorPoint != new Point(0, 0))
            {
                checkToResizeSides = true;
            }
            else
            {
                checkToResizeSides = false;
            }
        }
        Invalidate();
    }
    protected virtual void Mouse_Up(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (numberOfElipse == 0)
        {
            dictOfPoints = new Dictionary<int, List<Point>>();
        dictToMoveSides = new Dictionary<int, List<Point>>();
        }
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left && checkBox1.Checked)
        {
            dictOfPoints.Add(numberOfElipse, new List<Point>() { point, newMousePosition });

            dictToMoveSides.Add(numberOfElipse, new List<Point>() {
            new Point(newMousePosition.X, point.Y + (newMousePosition.Y - point.Y) / 2),
            new Point(point.X + (newMousePosition.X - point.X) / 2, newMousePosition.Y),
            new Point(point.X, point.Y + (newMousePosition.Y - point.Y) / 2),
            new Point(point.X + (newMousePosition.X - point.X) / 2, point.Y)});

            numberOfElipse++;
        }
    }
    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Mouse_Down(e);
    }
    protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Mouse_Move(e);
    }
    protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Mouse_Up(e);
    }
    protected virtual void On_Paint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics graphics = e.Graphics;
        if (checkBox1.Checked)
            graphics.DrawEllipse(pen, point.X, point.Y, newMousePosition.X - point.X, newMousePosition.Y - point.Y);
        if (dictOfPoints != null)
        {
            foreach (var i in dictOfPoints.Keys)
            {
                graphics.DrawEllipse(pen, dictOfPoints[i][0].X, dictOfPoints[i][0].Y,
                    dictOfPoints[i][1].X - dictOfPoints[i][0].X, dictOfPoints[i][1].Y - dictOfPoints[i][0].Y);
            }
        }
        if (ChangeColorPoint != new Point(0, 0))
        {
            graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Red), ChangeColorPoint.X - 3, ChangeColorPoint.Y - 3,
                6, 6);
        }
    }
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        On_Paint(e);
    }
    protected virtual Point FindNecessaryPoint(Point pt)
    {
        if (dictToMoveSides != null)
        {
            foreach (var i in dictToMoveSides.Keys)
            {
                foreach (var j in dictToMoveSides[i])
                {
                    if (j.X + 15 > pt.X && j.X - 15 < pt.X && j.Y + 15 > pt.Y && j.Y - 15 < pt.Y)
                    {
                        indexToResize = i;
                        return new Point(j.X, j.Y);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        indexToResize = int.MaxValue;
        return new Point(0, 0);
    }
    protected virtual void Replace(int index)
    {
        dictToMoveSides.Remove(index);
        dictToMoveSides.Add(index, new List<Point>() {
            new Point(newMousePosition.X, point.Y + (newMousePosition.Y - point.Y) / 2),
            new Point(point.X + (newMousePosition.X - point.X) / 2, newMousePosition.Y),
            new Point(point.X, point.Y + (newMousePosition.Y - point.Y) / 2),
            new Point(point.X + (newMousePosition.X - point.X) / 2, point.Y)});
    }
    protected virtual void Resize(int indexToMoveSide, int differenceX, int differenceY)
    {
        if (indexToMoveSide <= 1)
        {
            if (indexToMoveSide == 0)
            {
                differenceY = 0;
            }
            else if (indexToMoveSide == 1)
            {
                differenceX = 0;
            }
            dictOfPoints[indexToResize][1] = new Point(dictOfPoints[indexToResize][1].X - differenceX, dictOfPoints[indexToResize][1].Y - differenceY);
            newMousePosition = new Point(newMousePosition.X - differenceX, newMousePosition.Y - differenceY);
            ChangeColorPoint = new Point(ChangeColorPoint.X - differenceX, ChangeColorPoint.Y - differenceY);
        }
        else
        {
            if (indexToMoveSide == 2)
            {
                differenceY = 0;
            }
            else if (indexToMoveSide == 3)
            {
                differenceX = 0;
            }
            dictOfPoints[indexToResize][0] = new Point(dictOfPoints[indexToResize][0].X - differenceX, dictOfPoints[indexToResize][0].Y - differenceY);
            point = new Point(point.X - differenceX, point.Y - differenceY);
            ChangeColorPoint = new Point(ChangeColorPoint.X - differenceX, ChangeColorPoint.Y - differenceY);
        }
    }
} 


partial class Rectangle : Ellipse
{
    static int numberOfRectangle = 0;
    protected override int indexToResize { get; set; }

    protected override Dictionary<int, List<Point>> dictOfPoints { get; set; }
    protected override Dictionary<int, List<Point>> dictToMoveSides { get; set; }

    protected override bool checkToResizeSides { get; set; }

    protected override CheckBox checkBox1 { get; set; }

    protected override Point point { get; set; }
    protected override Point newMousePosition { get; set; }
    protected override Point movingMouse { get; set; }
    protected override Point ChangeColorPoint { get; set; }

    Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 3);

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Application.Run(new Ellipse());
    }
    public Rectangle():base()
    {
        
        checkBox1.Text = "Rectangle";
        checkBox1.Size = new Size(100, 30);
        checkBox1.Location = new Point(400, 50);
    }
    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.Mouse_Down(e);
    }
    protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.Mouse_Move(e);
    }
    protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
       Mouse_Up(e);
    }
    protected override void Mouse_Up(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (numberOfRectangle == 0)
        {
            dictOfPoints = new Dictionary<int, List<Point>>();
            dictToMoveSides = new Dictionary<int, List<Point>>();
        }
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left && checkBox1.Checked)
        {
            dictOfPoints.Add(numberOfRectangle, new List<Point>() { point, newMousePosition });

            dictToMoveSides.Add(numberOfRectangle, new List<Point>() {
            new Point(newMousePosition.X, newMousePosition.Y),
            new Point(point.X, point.Y)});

            numberOfRectangle++;
        }
    }
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        On_Paint(e);
    }
    protected override void On_Paint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics graphics = e.Graphics;
        if (checkBox1.Checked)
            graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, point.X, point.Y, newMousePosition.X - point.X, newMousePosition.Y - point.Y);
        if (dictOfPoints != null)
        {
            foreach (var i in dictOfPoints.Keys)
            {
                graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, Math.Min(dictOfPoints[i][0].X, dictOfPoints[i][1].X),
                    Math.Min(dictOfPoints[i][0].Y, dictOfPoints[i][1].Y),
                    Math.Abs(dictOfPoints[i][1].X - dictOfPoints[i][0].X), Math.Abs(dictOfPoints[i][1].Y - dictOfPoints[i][0].Y));
            }
        }
        if (ChangeColorPoint != new Point(0, 0))
        {
            graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Red), ChangeColorPoint.X - 3, ChangeColorPoint.Y - 3,
                6, 6);
        }
    }
    protected override void Replace(int index)
    {
        dictToMoveSides.Remove(index);
        dictToMoveSides.Add(index, new List<Point>() {
            new Point(newMousePosition.X, newMousePosition.Y),
            new Point(point.X, point.Y)});
    }
    protected override Point FindNecessaryPoint(Point pt)
    {
        return base.FindNecessaryPoint(pt);
    }
    protected override void Resize(int indexToMoveSide, int differenceX, int differenceY)
    {
            if (indexToMoveSide == 0)
            {
                dictOfPoints[indexToResize][1] = new Point(dictOfPoints[indexToResize][1].X - differenceX, dictOfPoints[indexToResize][1].Y - differenceY);
                newMousePosition = new Point(newMousePosition.X - differenceX, newMousePosition.Y - differenceY);
                ChangeColorPoint = new Point(ChangeColorPoint.X - differenceX, ChangeColorPoint.Y - differenceY);

            }
            else
            {
                dictOfPoints[indexToResize][0] = new Point(dictOfPoints[indexToResize][0].X - differenceX, dictOfPoints[indexToResize][0].Y - differenceY);
                point = new Point(point.X - differenceX, point.Y - differenceY);
                ChangeColorPoint = new Point(ChangeColorPoint.X - differenceX, ChangeColorPoint.Y - differenceY);
            }
    }
}


Я что-то не понял - зачем наследоваться от класса, если потом оверрайдить все свойства и методы класса-родителя? Вам необходимо еще раз почитать про ООП

Оставьте в родительском классе все общие свойства и методы, логика которых одинакова для экземпляров обоих классов - родителя и потомка, а в потомке переопределяйте те методы, которые имеют отличающееся поведение и логику. Например, перемещение эллипса и прямоугольника ничем принципиально не отличаются - оставляем только в родительском классе, а вот отрисовка будет у каждого своя
